# Select count(*) from another select in spring data

Tags: postgresql, select, count, group-by, spring-data

I Have this query in my JpaRepository that work's fine :

```
@Query("select ts.talent from T_LinkTalentSkill ts where ts.skill || '_'||ts.lnLevel in ('1_1','9_1') group by 1 having count(*)=2")
public List<T_Talent> searchBySkillTalent();
```

but All i want is to add count(*) i tried this query but it dosen't works

Ps : that works in my database (postgresql)

```
@Query("select count(*) from(select ts.talent from T_LinkTalentSkill ts where ts.skill || '_'||ts.lnLevel in ('1_1','9_1') group by 1 having count(*)=2)As temp")
public List<T_Talent> searchBySkillTalent();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Do you get any exception? You can't expect the second method to return a `List`, it should be `Integer` or `Long`.

Comment: I change it to long but it dosen't work anymore i got the same error :org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Comment: Have you tested the query in your dB administration tool?